# Merge and rename [androidq] and [android-10.0-q] to [android-10.0]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

There are currently two tags which refer to Android version 10.0, first [android-10.0-q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-10.0-q) with three questions and [androidq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/androidq) with 117 questions

All the previous version of Android were in the format [android-versionno-versionname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-versionno-versionname) example [android-9.0-pie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-9.0-pie), but as [Google deserts desserts](https://www.theverge.com/2019/8/22/20827231/android-10-q-google-name-officially-announced-new-logo-wordmark-desserts), Android 10.0 which was supposed to be Android Q____(name of some desert with Q) is now just called as Android 10.

So how should be name future android version tags? Calling it  [android-10.0-android10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-10.0-android10) looks odd. I guess it would be good if we just stick with version numbers from now on. So I am suggesting we name it as [android-10.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-10.0). What do you guys/gals suggest?

Comment: Somehow related on Android.SE: [How to name tags for Android 10?](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2566)

Comment: ya seems like [android.stackexchange.com](https://android.stackexchange.com) having similar problem with android 10 . This question is also a tag synonym and retag request so I am gonna let it stay .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by Andrew T in the [linked synonym request on Android Enthusiasts](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2567):

> I think android-10 is appropriate with android-q as the synonym. This is also according to what Google uses on its blog.

Therefore, have [android-10.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-10.0) as the tag does make sense. I have renamed the tag [androidq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/androidq) to [android-10.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-10.0) and added [android-10.0-q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-10.0-q) as a synonym, that is: [android-10.0-q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-10.0-q) (x 12) → [android-10.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-10.0) (x 131)